# laravel set deleted_at has problem with subqueries

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

first things first I have *repositories* and *services* in my laravel app.

#### Main Problem

My main problem is laravel is not compatible with sub-queries and not support them well!

- **I use below versions:**

  - laravel v10.16.1
  - php 8.1
- **I have `deleted_at`, `updated_at` and `created_at` columns**

##### Problem with `deleted_at`

If I use soft delete trait and want `deleted_at` to handle automatically, when I use sub queries like below, it'll show me error:

```php
class UserRepository {
    ...

    public function getWhere(array $columns, Builder $where)
    {
        $query = $this->model
            ->newQuery()
            ->when($where, function (Builder $query) use ($where) {
                $query->fromSub($where, 'sub');
            });

        return $query->get($columns);
    }

    ...
}
```

```
ERROR: `'deleted_at' column does not exists`
```

**Problematic query Example**

```sql
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name`='john') AS `sub` WHERE `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
```

In above query, `deleted_at` is not exist but it exists in database and this is because of sub-query alias.

I search about it and it seems to be laravel issue some how and finally I removed automatic soft deletes and do it manually like below:

```php
class UserRepository {
    ...
    
    public function getWhere(array $columns, Builder $where)
    {
        $prefix = $this->model->getTable();
        $query = $this->model
            ->newQuery()
            ->when($where, function (Builder $query) use ($where, &$prefix) {
                $prefix = 'sub';
                $query->fromSub($where, $prefix);
            });

        $query->whereNull($prefix . '.deleted_at');

        return $query->get($columns);
    }

    ...
}
```

**What Should I do?**

(I hope my explanation is understandable)

*Thanks in advanced.*

---

## EDIT

I changed my example because I was doing wrong for `update` operation and `updated_at` is not problematic in my case but sub-query and set `deleted_at` has problem.

Comment: You should add the error messages (as text messages) you write about near to that writing about that you're getting an error so that it is more speaking (e.g in the deleted_at scenario you describe, probably above the code block).

Comment: @hakre Thanks for comment. For `deleted_at` error: `'deleted_at' column does not exists` (because of sub query alias) and for `updated_at` error I mentioned it.

Comment: better put it into the question, not in comments. as you have seen that so often now, it's clear for you, but for readers its often helpful if you make it visible to them, too. I'd do 1. short description, 2. the error message, 3. the SQL and 4. the code that generates it. So you go in from the outside to the inside. E.g. error says problem in query, query shows the cause/relation, and then code shows how you messed it up ;) (sorry don't know much of this eloquent?)

Comment: @hakre I put my error in question but I couldn't make it shorter because it looses some description. Thanks anyway

Comment: oh sorry if I created the impression that your description would have been too long, I only elaborated why I think (and in which order it _could_ make more sense to me), and that was entirely after the description. but short descriptions are always welcome for your readers ;)

Comment: And as written, I'm not that eloquent, but if I understand it right, the SQL building is related to the model., perhaps share a bit of how the model is implemented. I guess it has that trait you're writing about? And perhaps you can trick that builder if you replace `'sub'` with `'users'`? (don't test on the production db...)

Comment: Just a note on _"I want my service be able to create complex where clauses."_ fyi: You normally have the repository for that, the service just calls the appropriate method on the repository with the parameters needed, and the repository takes care of the complex details. Otherwise you shift the complexity away from the repository that will only make it more complex. Just take it with you, you may need to let this kind of thinking settle a bit.

Comment: @hakre The trait is was talking about is `solftDeletes` from laravel core library and ofcourse, I know that we should not make services to have direct access to building the query(It was mostly a test if I can do it without side effects), nut anyway if I put my where clause in repository, same problem will happen again regardless.

Comment: Yes, that's only note, and I think not related at all to your concrete question about the query building or better the SQL result out of it.

Comment: As in the answer to the duplicate, using `withTrashed()` will prevent Eloquent from adding on the `WHERE deleted_at IS NULL` clause. Manually filter on the `deleted_at` column of the subquery if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, usually when you create a Schema with `$table->softDeletes();` it will automatically create the `deleted_at` column in the table. So I'm not sure why you get `deleted_at` doesn't exist.

An example of a schema is like this.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('able_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->softDeletes();  // This adds the deleted_at column
    });
}
```

> After this, you have to run the migration. `php artisan migrate` if the first time, to drop all and re-run `php artisan migrate:fresh`

As well, when use use `use SoftDeletes;` it will automatically add global scope to all queries, like ***where `deleted_at` is null.***

> **If you use this in the given order, this will work like a piece of cake. Nothing goes wrong and simple as that**

---

To fix your issue in an alternative way, you can add `withoutTrashed()` to your query.

```
public function getWhere(array $columns, Builder $where)
{
    $query = $this->model
        ->newQuery()
        ->withoutTrashed()
        ->when($where, function (Builder $query) use ($where) {
            $query->fromSub($where, 'sub');
        });

    return $query->get($columns);
}
```

> ***But consider my first suggestion, Because it's the proper way to handle it and you don't have to put extra effort into this.***

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I get `column not found` because laravel adds table's name before column like: `users.deleted_at IS NULL` and sub query is like `select * from (select * from table_name where ....) as sub where users.deleted_at IS NULL`. There is no `users` it is `sub` and it should be `sub.deleted_at IS NULL`. Using `withoutTrashed()` method is like not using `softDeletes` trait and do it manually

Answer (score -1):

I don't quite understand what you are trying to do, but I think I can help you

You can just try this

```
$query = yourModelName::where('name' , 'john')->get();
```

To make this

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name`='john') AS `sub` WHERE `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
```

If you are trying to bind a foreign key to a primary in laravel try this

add this to "users" model

```
public function post() {
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

and add this to other model "posts"

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

then you can get any things you want from 2 table like this

```
$post[0]->title //title of post table
$post[0]->user->name //name of user table
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have relations but this is not what I meant. I need to know how can I implement `User::fromSub($query, 'sub')->get()` but my `deleted_at` or `updated_at` knows what was the alias and don't just set `users` before them but put `sub` alias